# Website inaccessible from Ubuntu command prompt but is accessible from browser

Tags: command-line, networking, curl, javascript, nmap

When I visit a website from the browser it exists, but when I check with the Ubuntu command line it pings but nothing else works. Nmap does nothing. Curl does nothing. The only vaguely interesting result is wget:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  parent.window.location.assign("/login");
</script>
```

I need to run proper tests on this website, but all the people who set it up or have the faintest clue about technical matters have left in a very short period, so I am the only person with technical skills and they need it fixed. They won't be able to tell me how to access it via anything but the frontend.

I need to understand the full technology so I can deploy new instances.

Where should I start?

Comment: Can you include the `wget` command you are using along with its output lines from the terminal?

Comment: Might by related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1324421/797250

Comment: The actual website url?